# "Why would he have stolen the car?" vs "Why would he have to steal the car?"

Tags: conditional-constructions, past-perfect, interrogatives

I'm trying to feel the difference between the sentences:

- "Why would he **have stolen** the car?"
- "Why would he **have to steal** the car?"

I'm feeling that both have a common idea of asking the reason behind the assumption of him stealing a car.

Comment: The first is asking about **why** he stole the car, the second asks about his motivations for doing so.

Comment: When you **have to do** something, you are *compelled* to do it, because someone is commanding you, or because circumstances demand it, or you have a psychological compulsion to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sentence:

> Why would he **have stolen** the car?

Asks why a person stole the car. It asks for a reason why. Possible reasons are, they were running away from the police. Or maybe he steals cars and sells them for money. Its simply asking for a motivation

> Why would he **have to steal** the car?

Implies that the thief felt that they had no choice *but* to steal, hence the phrase "have to", and the person is asking why the thief felt this way. For example, if a very wealthy man was stealing cars, people would ask "Why does he have to steal? He can buy all the cars he wants"